# Splitting Concatenated FOR in SQL PIVOT

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

I have this query below using Dynamic SQL to create new columns and pivot them out, however `[MonthList]` field is concatenated and would require to split it somehow as currently it puts `[Monthly Rate]` values only if `[MonthList] = @PivotColumns` name

Example of table:
[image]

Current Code:

```
Set @SQLQuery = 
    N'SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[TableA] 
    PIVOT( sum([Monthly Rate])
FOR [MonthsList] IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) as P'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to come up with an answer using Cursor. If anyones interested heres how:

```
DECLARE @Q NVARCHAR(4000),
@CName VARCHAR(255)

DECLARE ColCur CURSOR
FOR
SELECT C.name as Column_name
FROM sys.columns C
LEFT JOIN sys.tables t
on C.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'TableA'

OPEN ColCur

FETCH NEXT FROM ColCur INTO @CName


WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS =0)
BEGIN

SET @Q = 
case when @CName like '___''__' then
'UPDATE TableA
SET ['+@CName+'] = [Monthly Rate]
WHERE [MonthsList] like ''%'+replace(@CName,char(39),char(39)+char(39))+'%'''
Else ''
end
--print @q
EXEC sp_executesql @Q

FETCH NEXT FROM ColCur INTO @CName

END

CLOSE ColCur
DEALLOCATE ColCur
```